# How to get views and comment count when using Youtube data api -v3 playlistItems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, youtube-data-api, redux-saga

I'm trying to get some data using Youtube data api -v3 `playlistItems`. I'm able to get all the data that comes with `playlistItems` perfectly. However, I need more data than what `playlistItems` offers. For example, I would like to get the view counts, comment count, and all the statistics

I know I could use `/youtube/v3/videos` to get the statistics but I have been trying this and it is not working for me. Please help. Thanks.

```js
export function buildVideosRequest(amount = 12, loadDescription = false, nextPageToken) {
  let fields = 'nextPageToken,prevPageToken,items(contentDetails/videoId,id,snippet(channelId,channelTitle,publishedAt,thumbnails/medium,title)),pageInfo(totalResults)';
  if (loadDescription) {
    fields += ',items/snippet/description';
  }
  return buildApiRequest('GET',
    '/youtube/v3/playlistItems',
    {
      part: 'snippet,contentDetails',
      maxResults: amount,
      playlistId: 'PLvahqwMqN4M0zIUkkXUW1JOgBARhbIz2e',
      pageToken: nextPageToken,
      fields,
    }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon invoking the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint, you obtain a result set of which each item is a [`playlistItems resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource-representation) JSON object.

That JSON object doesn't contain the info you're interested in (view count, comment count, etc). This kind of info -- as you alluded yourself -- is obtainable through the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint.

That is that you have to collect all video IDs that you're interested in into an array, then invoke repeatedly the `Videos.list` endpoint, passing to it an [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) parameter assigned properly.

Note that this endpoint's `id` property allows you to reduce the number of endpoint calls, since the `id` may be specified as a comma-separated list of video IDs (at most 50). Hence, if you have for example an array of 114 video ID's, then you may issue only 3 calls to `Videos.list`.